# SQLAlchemy with on connection (python)

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I understand that with the standard `MySQLdb` driver, you usually use a `with` statement to ensure that the connection is closed with `__exit__`.

Is there an equivalent `with` statement that I need for SQLAlchemy `sessions` or maybe the `engine`? Or is the manual timeout to close connections sufficient for SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quote from docs:

> Most web frameworks include infrastructure to establish a single
>   Session, associated with the request, which is correctly constructed
>   and torn down corresponding torn down at the end of a request. Such
>   infrastructure pieces include products such as Flask-SQLAlchemy, for
>   usage in conjunction with the Flask web framework, and
>   Zope-SQLAlchemy, for usage in conjunction with the Pyramid and Zope
>   frameworks. SQLAlchemy strongly recommends that these products be used
>   as available.
>
> In those situations where integration libraries are not available,
>   SQLAlchemy includes its own “helper” class known as scoped_session.

So, looks like [scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.scoping.scoped_session) is what you are talking about. [Documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#contextual-thread-local-sessions) on how to use scoped sessions is pretty good. Basically, you define when to open the session and when to close it (see [Using Custom Created Scopes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html#using-custom-created-scopes)):

```
from my_web_framework import get_current_request, on_request_end
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker

Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=some_engine), scopefunc=get_current_request)

@on_request_end
def remove_session(req):
    Session.remove()
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase you are looking for is a "[context manager](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)", which is an object that adheres to the attribute naming convention needed to be used in a `with` statement. See ["Working with the Engine"](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/connections.html#using-transactions) in the docs for working with a context manager for engine connections:

```
with engine.begin() as connection:
    r1 = connection.execute(table1.select())
    connection.execute(table1.insert(), col1=7, col2='this is some data')
```

As best as I can tell, there is no such functionality for a Session object itself.